# Mock php functions

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, symfony4

I make a symfony 4 reusable bundle for my projects.
I want to test it with a coverage nearby 100%.
But i don't know how to test some part of my code who depends of php functions.

example :

```
public function getStatusCode(\Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface) {
        return $exception->getStatusCode();
    }
    if (is_a($exception, "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException")) {
        return Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED; // I want to test this
    }
    return Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
}
```

I try to use getMockBuilder but the mock's class is not correct.

Is there a way to mock or replace is_a or to create a mock whose class is the same as that in condition?

Comment: Why can't you use `instanceof` instead of `is_a`?

Comment: Why do you need a mock ? Which method calls to you want to mock ? Passing an `AccessDeniedException` seems like the simplest way to test if the status code is correctly returned from this method.

Comment: I want to use is_a because i want the method works without the security bundle
Maybe the solution is just to add the security bundle in project dev requires

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to mock this function, you can use this package: https://packagist.org/packages/hjerichen/prophecy-php

This is a simple example for a test method in a PHPUnit TestCase.

```php
$php = $this->prophesizePHP(__NAMESPACE__);
$php->is_a($exception, "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException")->willReturn(true);
$php->reveal()
```